# trying to record on a blank cassette via aux, but external mic is also recording

Tags: recording, homerecording

I’m trying to record on my Panasonic RQ-345 (Portable cassette player/ recorder) using an auxiliary cord connected to my phone, I can hear the audio im trying to record, but I can hear the outside audio as well over it so im guessing the external mic is also recording along with the aux, how can I make this stop?? Ive looked everywhere on google for answers but I cant find anything on this

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about music practise or performance & would require detailed knowledge of the operational foibles of a 40-year-old dictation recorder.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the service manual and the aux connector is an **output** not an **input**. I don't think there's any way (without modifying the circuitry) to record a line in signal; you can only record from the microphone.